# Error in ASP.NET MVC with decimal data type with ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to populate the data for a ComboBox from Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC3 page. In Models, I added DataRepository.cs :

```
    public List<SelectListItem> GetBookPrices()
    {
        var BookPrice = (from bookPrice in ddlEntity.tblBook
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Text = Convert.ToString(bookPrice .Price),
                              Value = Convert.ToString(bookPrice.Price)
                          }).Distinct();
        return BookPrice .ToList();
    }
```

and DDLProperty.cs:

```
    public decimal PriceId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> PriceValue { get; set; }
```

In my database, I have a Price column as a decimal. I can do the binding correctly for a DropDownList with a varchar datatype without any error, but I could not figure out how to fix the above code to work with it being a decimal.

Here is my Controller:

```
    DataRepository objRepository = new DataRepository();

    public ActionResult Price()
    {
        DDLProperties objDDL = new DDLProperties();
        objDDL.PriceValue = objRepository.GetBookPrices();

        return View(objDDL);
    }
```

Here is the error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

It points to the following line: return BookPrice .ToList();

I am starting to learn MVC, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BookPrice.ToList()` is the line in which your query is actually being run. Entity Framework uses deferred execution on most of its functions, so the query is only being run when you are actually calling for the data, as you are with calling ToList().

That being said, what you're trying to do in GetBookPrices() above is actually putting that select statement into the actual database query itself. That's where you get Entity Framework telling you that it has no idea what to do with the ToString() method on your prices. ToString is not actually something that it recognizes in that context.

To solve this problem, I recommend you split out the database call and the conversion into the select list as follows:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetBookPrices()
{
    var Books = ddlEntity.tblBook.ToList();
    var BookPrice = Books.Select(bookPrice => new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                              Text = Convert.ToString(bookPrice .Price),
                                              Value = Convert.ToString(bookPrice.Price)
                                             }).Distinct();
    return BookPrice.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my error issue. The Disctinct in LINQ was not working well. How do I get the unique records and eliminate the duplicated records in above LINQ?

Comment: There is an overload for Distinct that takes in a comparer to actually use for seeing if two objects are equal. You could implement your own comparer for this case as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx